# Is it possible to use a Limiting Modulator Driver as an amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, driver, microwave

The [MTC5525](http://datasheet.elcodis.com/pdf2/89/57/895732/mtc5522.pdf) is basically a Limiting Modulator Driver for driving LiNbO3 modulators, which for me, says nothing, even after googling for 1 hour.

But the seller says it can be used as a power amplifier.
I have some doubts about that. So, my questions are:

q1: In few words, what is this limiting modulator amplifier supposed to do?

q2: can it be used as a power amplifier, to amplify a monochromatic sinusoidal signal?

**Note**: in my case, the input signal comes from YIG spheres oscillators, with amplitude of about 0.5V to 1 V (15 dbm) , and it ranges from 500MHz to 10GHz.

Comment: LiNbO3 (lithium niobate) crystals are electro-optic materials which have the property of having an index of refraction that varies as a function of a local electric field. They are used as light (usually laser) modulators. The application for this amplifier is essentially digital. Depending upon what you want as output it may amplify your signal, but Q would likely suffer.